# Altering the column in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005. When I try to set the primary key constraint for a column in the alter statement. it committed error. i used this following query,

```
alter table "table name" modify(field__name integer(size) primary key);
```

can u say what the error actually.. expect ur valuable answer.. if u know other methods send me the query..

Answer (score 0):

Plese ensure the column data has unique values before adding a primary key constraint to that column

also the syntax seems to be wrong in your statement. For SQL server, ALTER syntax is given below -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] ADD PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2)
```

etc. if the columns already exist. But this sort if thing is much easier to do with the tools in Management Studio rather than through SQL if it's a one-off change.